# How to direct to default landing page with basic-auth middleware in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authorization

I'm trying to add basic authorization to an entire site on Express. If a user enters the correct credentials, then I would like the standard landing page to display. If not, then the user should be brought to an "access denied" page. I'm trying to figure out how to alter the [basic-auth middleware](https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth) example to accomplish this:

```
var http = require('http')
var auth = require('basic-auth')

// Create server
  var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var credentials = auth(req)

  if (!credentials || credentials.name !== 'john' || credentials.pass !== 'secret') {
    res.statusCode = 401
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"')
    res.end('Access denied')
  } else {
    res.end('Access granted')
  }
})
```

If I use `next();` instead of `res.end()`, I get an `undefined` error.

```
  var server = http.createServer(function (req, res, next) {
  var credentials = auth(req)

  if (!credentials || credentials.name !== 'john' || credentials.pass !== 'secret') {
    res.statusCode = 401
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"')
    res.end('Access denied')
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

This is what my routes look like:

```
app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing'));

  // . . . 

  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
.get(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` is a construction of `connect` which is a middleware library underlying the Express web server. But you're passing your own handler function to the http server. You should make the http server use the express app to handle requests. Then express's middleware makes it simple.

```
var http = require('http');
var auth = require('basic-auth');
var app = require('express')();
var server = http.Server(app);
server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', ensureCredentials, function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
})
app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/');
})
function ensureCredentials(req, res, next){
  // do logic
  if(){
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Its important to understand that Express doesn't execute any middlewares after a response is sent with `res.send(), res.json(), res.end(), res.redirect()`. So in one situation (`/` with bad auth), the `ensureCredentials` function sends a 403 and the `app.get('/')` handler won't be run. In another situation, the auth checks out, `next()` is called, and the `app.get('/')` handler is run.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, when I use the code above, I'm not getting the username/password prompt. The page loads as usual. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe that's what the headers are for... maybe you always fail the first try and use the header to tell the browser "show an auth hint". Try setting the headers in the `ensureCredentials` 403 response. Also, if you didn't know you can manually pass credentials in a request with `https://user:password@domain.com/`

Comment: Oh, well, the page loads every time because i skipped all the auth logic... you need to put something in the `if(){`...

Comment: Page is loading even though I added `!credentials || credentials.name !== 'john' || credentials.pass !== 'secret'` in the `if()`